# Sequence of tenses when the main clause is in "present perfect"

Tags: grammar

Do the tenses match in the following sentences?

- John, two years ago you left India and settled in Australia for a good job. I hope Australia ***has given*** you the things that this country ***did not give/has not given*** you.

Note that John is still in Australia when I am saying this.

Answer (score 1):

The first verb phrase, 'has given', has the correct tense. Since he is still in Australia, present perfect is the appropriate tense.

For the second case, I choose the past simple 'did not give', because he doesn't live in this country (India) anymore. However, 'has not given' doesn't sound incorrect here.